# Google Maps and Ionic not working

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

I downloaded the geolocation plugin :

> http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/

this is the code in my html file:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

and this is the code in my controller :

```
var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};


$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(3.1275345, 101.64342239999996);

                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: latLng,
                        zoom: 15,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

                }, function(error){
                    console.log("Could not get location"  + JSON.stringify(error));
                });
```

the error however, doesn't show anything.
The error is

> Could not get location{}

How do I fix this ?

Comment: just want to make sure, did you create API key for use in our application for google map?
btw you can also take a look at this tutorial and follow it
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/

Comment: Please, be sure you are running ionic on a Secure Origin https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features, one alternative is to run on localhost. `ionic serve --address localhost`